# after migration from typo3 7.6 to ver 12.4.5 I have got this error

Tags: typoscript, typo3-12.x

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this error in TYPO3 Typoscript vers 12.4.5?
Maybe it is important: My System is a WINDOWS SERVER 2022 with ENGLISH Language. Maybe I need to add language pack in windows server?

```
    Tue, 24 Oct 2023 06:46:56 +0000 [ERROR] request="b4711f1859b0c" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Localization.Locales": Locale "de_DE" and  "de_DE" not found. 
    Tue, 24 Oct 2023 06:46:58 +0000 [CRITICAL] request="b4711f1859b0c" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.DebugExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: FE): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception, code #1476107295, file C:\Apache24\htdocs\InstituteT12ok\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\ErrorHandler.php, line 138: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "L" in C:\Apache24\htdocs\InstituteT12ok\vendor\symfony\expression-language\Node\GetAttrNode.php line 130- Exception: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "L" in C:\Apache24\htdocs\InstituteT12ok\vendor\symfony\expression-language\Node\GetAttrNode.php line 130, in file C:\Apache24\htdocs\InstituteT12ok\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\ErrorHandler.php:138 - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"FE","exception_class":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\Exception","exception_code":1476107295,"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\ErrorHandler.php","line":138,"message":"PHP Warning: Undefined array key \"L\" in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\vendor\\symfony\\expression-language\\Node\\GetAttrNode.php line 130","request_url":"https://www.physiological-chemistry.at/","exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\Exception: PHP Warning: Undefined array key \"L\" in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\vendor\\symfony\\expression-language\\Node\\GetAttrNode.php line 130 in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\ErrorHandler.php:138\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\vendor\\symfony\\expression-language\\Node\\GetAttrNode.php(130): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\Apache24\\\\htd...', 130)\n#1 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\vendor\\symfony\\expression-language\\Node\\BinaryNode.php(98): Symfony\\Component\\ExpressionLanguage\\Node\\GetAttrNode->evaluate(Array, Array)\n#2 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\vendor\\symfony\\expression-language\\ExpressionLanguage.php(59): Symfony\\Component\\ExpressionLanguage\\Node\\BinaryNode->evaluate(Array, Array)\n#3 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\ExpressionLanguage\\Resolver.php(73): Symfony\\Component\\ExpressionLanguage\\ExpressionLanguage->evaluate('request.getQuer...', Array)\n#4 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Visitor\\IncludeTreeConditionMatcherVisitor.php(163): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\ExpressionLanguage\\Resolver->evaluate('request.getQuer...')\n#5 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser.php(47): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Visitor\\IncludeTreeConditionMatcherVisitor->visitBeforeChildren(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\IncludeNode\\ConditionInclude), 3)\n#6 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser.php(50): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser->traverseRecursive(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\IncludeNode\\ConditionInclude), Array, 3)\n#7 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser.php(50): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser->traverseRecursive(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\IncludeNode\\IncludeTyposcriptInclude), Array, 2)\n#8 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser.php(50): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser->traverseRecursive(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\IncludeNode\\SysTemplateInclude), Array, 1)\n#9 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser.php(41): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser->traverseRecursive(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\IncludeNode\\RootInclude), Array, 0)\n#10 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController.php(1371): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\Traverser\\IncludeTreeTraverser->traverse(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\TypoScript\\IncludeTree\\IncludeNode\\RootInclude), Array)\n#11 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\PrepareTypoScriptFrontendRendering.php(53): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController->getFromCache(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#12 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PrepareTypoScriptFrontendRendering->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#13 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\TypoScriptFrontendInitialization.php(113): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#14 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\TypoScriptFrontendInitialization->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#15 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\PageArgumentValidator.php(114): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#16 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PageArgumentValidator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#17 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\PreviewSimulator.php(90): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#18 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PreviewSimulator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#19 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\PageResolver.php(102): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#20 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PageResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#21 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\StaticRouteResolver.php(64): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#22 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\StaticRouteResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#23 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\ContentSecurityPolicyReporter.php(42): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#24 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\ContentSecurityPolicyReporter->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#25 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\SiteBaseRedirectResolver.php(90): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#26 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\SiteBaseRedirectResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#27 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\FrontendUserAuthenticator.php(73): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#28 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\FrontendUserAuthenticator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#29 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\BackendUserAuthenticator.php(79): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#30 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\BackendUserAuthenticator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#31 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Middleware\\RequestTokenMiddleware.php(71): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#32 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Middleware\\RequestTokenMiddleware->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#33 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\MaintenanceMode.php(51): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#34 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\MaintenanceMode->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#35 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\SiteResolver.php(55): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#36 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\SiteResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#37 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\EidHandler.php(49): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#38 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\EidHandler->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#39 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Middleware\\NormalizedParamsAttribute.php(41): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#40 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Middleware\\NormalizedParamsAttribute->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#41 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Middleware\\VerifyHostHeader.php(55): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#42 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Middleware\\VerifyHostHeader->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#43 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Middleware\\TimeTrackerInitialization.php(48): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#44 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(162): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\TimeTrackerInitialization->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous))\n#45 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(70): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#46 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\AbstractApplication.php(80): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#47 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\frontend\\Classes\\Http\\Application.php(59): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\AbstractApplication->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#48 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Http\\AbstractApplication.php(92): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\Application->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#49 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\index.php(20): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\AbstractApplication->run()\n#50 C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\InstituteT12ok\\index.php(21): {closure}()\n#51 {main}"}
```

Edit: I found this info: [HIT](https://talk.typo3.org/t/core-localization-locales-locale-de-de-and-de-de-not-found/4841)

I have added my templates dir, and it might be a reason in the typoscript because when I add my typoscript instead the default one I get this error.

```
    # Main Top Menu (Level 1)
    lib.mainMenu = HMENU
    lib.mainMenu {
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                stdWrap.field = uid
            }
            wrap = |
        }
        special = directory
        special.value = 1 # Root page ID
    }
    
    # Side Menu (Levels 2 to 4)
    lib.subMenu = HMENU
    lib.subMenu {
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }
        }
        2 < .1
        3 < .1
        4 < .1
        entryLevel = 1
    }
    
    # Language Selector
    lib.languages = HMENU
    lib.languages {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1,2 # List of language IDs
        special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                linkWrap = | |*| &nbsp;|&nbsp; |*| &nbsp;|&nbsp;
            }
        }
    }
    page = PAGE
    page {
        typeNum = 0
        shortcutIcon = fileadmin/templates/webteam/images/favicon.ico
        # Include CSS file
        includeCSS {
                file1 = fileadmin/templates/webteam/css/cms.css
                file2 = fileadmin/templates/webteam/css/base.css
                file3 = fileadmin/templates/webteam/css/mug_base.css
                file4 = fileadmin/templates/webteam/css/cockpit.css
                file5 = fileadmin/templates/webteam/css/menu.css
        }
    
        # Fluid Template Configuration
        10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
        10 {
            templateRootPaths.0 = fileadmin/templates/digitalblue/pages/
            templateName = Default.html
    
            # Variables for Fluid
            variables {
                mainMenu < lib.mainMenu
                subMenu < lib.subMenu
                content < styles.content.get
                languages < lib.languages
            }
        }
    }
```

I have checked also if I could deactivate the mentioned t3sbootstrap
extention but I have not installed it and I do not find any info where I could find the t3sbootstrap setup.

Edit: Now I have changed to typo3 12.4.7 and defined the de-DE LAnguage in my Windows SERVER 2022 and now I do get that the US language is not found.

`Locale "en_US.UTF-8" and  "en_US" not found.`

As I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055760/typo3-10-4-locale-en-us-utf-8-not-found) that I need to do a `locale -a` cmd but I have a WINDOWS SERVER 2022 System. How can be this checked?

Comment: Can you also share the code involved?

Comment: What do you mean by "here"? Please add all relevant information to your question instead of posting links to external ressources

Comment: Now I just have edited my post with the `setup.typoscript` but I did not post the `*.css `and `default.html` files

Comment: Please also share what you've tried to resolve the problem